# How to automatically close putty windows on a network issue?

Tags: putty

I often jump from one network to another and leave behind Putty ssh sessions that pop-up

[image]

Is there a way to force such windows to close automatically when the connection is down? (I do not care about the popup)

I tried two settings, but none of them fix the issue:

---

[image]

I that added to the Default profile but I do not think it applies to existing profiles (?)

---

[image]

Comment: I do not think you can avoid that message box.

Comment: I need the same feature. https://superuser.com/questions/430159 solves half the problem, but cannot get rid of the popup.

Answer (score -3):

You can Ctrl+Alt+Delete,

Or go into Activity Monitor or your App Processes in Task Manager -> 'Apps' then right click on app to get 'Properties' on what should be something like PuTTY.exe and any of the other Putty programs...ie. Puttygen, etc.

Set it to Manual startup or Disabled and on restart settings caused by errors configure your preferences of whether you want the program to close indefinitely (or until next open, while shutting down the processes associated as well, or if you want it to auto-restart). All those settings are in there. Task manager's one of the easiest ways to get there.

You could also do some sort of scripting similar to that of VPNs where if network has disruptions or anything but success, especially errored responses then close program. Look into open source VPNs on Github in Powershell, C#, PHP, Python. You would have to have it as a process that was triggered on launch or startup of application.

Comment: What are you even talking about? Putty is not a service, it’s just a regular desktop application.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My bad I meant to say Apps tab.

Comment: Do you want to close the ssh connection or the program?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The question is about closing the putty window if a connection is down. It pops up an information window that needs to be acknowledged for the main window to close.